# Old domain name appended to page titles in Google SERP

Tags: google-search, 301-redirect, search-results, title

We recently moved our domain from `monomachines.com --> supplychimp.com`
Followed all the recommendations from various blog posts and told Google in Webmaster Tools that `MonoMachines` is now `SupplyChimp`.  301 redirects are all setup and working properly.

**The Issue**:
Google is using our OLD company/domain name for the new website.
If you look at the indexed pages using `site:supplychimp.com` Google is using the wrong name.

Anyone know how/why Google is using our old name?  It's been 3 months now!

[image: Google SERPs with Wrong Domain Name]

Comment: This may take more time. After 3 months, you think the change would have an effect on some of the pages by now. Everything appears okay from what I can see. Google is clearly *branding* your SERP links. This is primarily because your title tags are short. If you change your title tags to lengths between 45-55 and possibly as long as about 60 characters, this may have updated already. I went through a similar process a few years back and with longer title tags and the transition was quick. Being shorter branded titles may be falling through a "crack" within the algorithm. Who knows? Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that 3 months may not be long enough.  We'll continue to monitor and hopefully google makes the switch soon.  I wish there was some way to let them know!

Comment: This thing is happening to me now as well and it is not an old domain in question, but just a phrase that I tend to use before and now I want to use another one, still google keeps adding it to almost all my pages with just a bit shorter title. So annoying ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to have more patience. Make sure you have changed the websites link from as many places possible. Especially from the popular ones.

I just noticed that you are using premium SSL which still has the old company's name. Also found a Twitter page which is linking to the blog page of the old website. You need to change all these links to quickly make Google understand that your website's name has been changed. Moreover, create your company's profile on popular social networks and other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I typed in mono machines in Google:

https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=i67jWK_fLKqC8Qfazb7ICg#q=mono+machines&*

It brings up your Google Business Listing on the right.

You have not updated your listing with Google and so it might be another point where Google is using old information.

Your social media accounts are still using the Mono Machines as well. Update all the information about your business and the Google algorithm will eventually change as it finds the new information.

Comment: Thanks Yan - we actually created new social media accounts as well as new google listings...those are all the old ones.  I wonder if we just need to shut those down.

Comment: I emailed your company to let you know a few more specifics issues that I found but received no response. I think one of the issues is that your old social media accounts, containing the old name still point to the old web address. But your old web address is forwarded to the new address. 
The algorithm might still be associating your old name with your new address because the old name listed on the social media effectively goes to the new address. (not sure if I am making myself clear)

Comment: At this point it's probably best to do a full social media and web directory audit to find all instances of your old name and start updating them. There are most likely many instances of incorrect data that you are unaware of.

Comment: Thanks for the insight I appreciate it!  A full social media and web directory audit is now in order.  I'll let you know how it goes.